Why is a secret key necessary for remember me tokens if they are validated against the database?
In Spring Security, remember me tokens are validated by comparing them with values stored in the database. Given this, why do we need a secret key for generating the tokens? What additional security does it provide?
This is what i am doing
@Bean
public PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices rememberMeServices() {
    PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices rememberMeServices =
            new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices("secretKey", userDetailsService, persistentTokenRepository);
    rememberMeServices.setAlwaysRemember(true);
    rememberMeServices.setUseSecureCookie(true);
    rememberMeServices.setTokenValiditySeconds(86400); // 24 horas en segundos
    return rememberMeServices;
}


after reading through the source code my interpretation is that the key is a hash that identifies which client the token is associated to. This gets handed out to the client, that sends it back and is then used as a key to identify that it comes from the correct client. But this was me just briefly reading through the source code on github in the browser.
